# How to avoid using break

Tags: java, reflection, conventions

I think `break` is here not the best solution to stop this method;

How can I stop the method, when I once set the object and entitiy manager; instead of using `break`;

```
/**
 * Convenience method for setting the given entity manager to the given
 * object via reflection.
 *
 * @param object the object whose entity manager should be set
 * @param em     the entity manager that should be set
 */
protected void setEntityManager(Object object, EntityManager em) {
    Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        if (f.getType().isAssignableFrom(EntityManager.class)) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                f.set(object, em);
                break;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the purpose of your code in prose.

Comment: Since you are breaking on the first field you can successfully set, there isn't really anything else you can write, other than `return`.

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable use of `break`

Comment: @PatrickParker I agree. Since the other alternative would be an iterator-guided loop with an additional boolean control variable: More boilerplate, in definitive.

Comment: You could use Java 8 streams, filter for isAssignableFrom and use findFirst to access the first matching element.

Comment: @RalfRenz no, because the predicate used in `findFirst` etc should have no side effects. This code requires the side effect of setting the field to determine if it is able to be set.

Comment: Are you willing to write additional methods to make the code simpler without the break statement, or simply looking to modify this existing method?

Comment: @BatScream simply looking to modify this existing method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought of using streams like this:

```
protected void setEntityManager(Object object, EntityManager em) {
    Optional<Field> f = Arrays.stream(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(x -> x.getType().isAssignableFrom(EntityManager.class)).findFirst();
    if (f.isPresent()) {
        f.get().setAccessible(true);
        try {
            f.get().set(object, em);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a very reasonable use for `break`.
If you still want to stop the loop and not use `break`, you  can use `return`, since it is allowed to `return;` in a method with return value of void.

Comment: Does that really exist, a "reasonable use for break" ?  Either you need to do something for ALL items in a collection, and then you don't want and don't need break, or else whatever you need to do is not for ALL items, and then the best option is to ADD code that makes that clear.  The predicate that subsets the items for which setAccessible() and set() are called (i.e. it being the first in the collection matching a certain other predicate) is NOWHERE visible as such in this code.  Is that "reasonable" ???  I personally don't really think so.

Comment: I can agree that the code is not "clean" and not very readable in the way it is presented here. We are not discussing the way it is written but the use of break. I agree that it is much more readable to add code that returns a filtered collection (or a single item if that is the case) on which we should call setAccessible() and set().

Comment: One can also use Java 8's .`filter()` and `findFirst()` along with `.orElse()`